# A question on Hölder inequality

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $p, q > 1$ such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Then
$$|\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_i y_i| \leq ||x||_p ||x||_q, \;\; \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$
I have to prove it considering
$$u = \frac{x}{||x||_p} \;\; \text{and} \;\; v = \frac{y}{||y||_q}$$
and using $\bf{Young's}$ inequality.
Can someone, please, give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: proofs of this inequality are everywhere online.

Comment: I didn't find a proof that considers $u = \frac{x}{||x||_p}, u = \frac{y}{||y||_q}, $

Comment: I have to use Young's inequality, not Jensen's inequality!

Comment: I don't know how. I need a hint

Comment: [Here's a relevant Wiki link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Proof_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ and $v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$.

1. By Young's inequality, $$|u_i \cdot v_i| \leq \frac{|u_i|^p}{p} + \frac{|v_i|^q}{q}. \tag{1}$$ Rewrite this inequality using the definition of $u$ and $v$.
2. Sum $(1)$ over $i=1,\ldots,n$. Deduce that $$\sum_{i=1}^n |u_i v_i| \leq 1.$$
3. Conclude.

Comment: I don't understand why $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |u_i v_i| \leq 1$. We have from (1) $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |u_i v_i| \leq \frac{1}{p} | \frac{x_i}{||x||_p}|^p +  \frac{1}{q} |\frac{y_i}{||y||_q}|^q.$$ And then?

Comment: @g.pomegranate And then 1/p+1/q = 1 as desired

Comment: Yes. In the right side we have $$\frac{1}{p} ||u||_p^p + \frac{1}{q} ||v||_q^q = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$$. Thank you!